# Using argparse with formatted positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to add a positional argument for a remote host and port with the format `remote:port`. While it does seem to work I can't quite figure out how to access the args.

```
parse.add_argument('--logfile')
parse.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
parse.add_argument('remote:port')
```

Attempting to exercise the script as follows:

```
$ python3 script.py --verbose localhost:5001
```

With the following code to print contents:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Prints the following:

```
Namespace(logfile=None, verbose=True, **{'remote:port': 'localhost:5001'})
```

But how can I access the `**` dictionary? And if my approach is entirely off base how might this be done? Though I did find `args._get_kwargs()` where one could access the args as an item in the list (of tuples), I do not want to depend on hardcoded indices.

Comment: Use ``vars(args)`` to get a dictionary of the arguments. Consider either renaming the parameter or its meta var, though.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!

Comment: You can't use that name as a `Namespace` attribute, but it's ok with `getattr`.  An alternative is to use `parser.add_argument('port', metavar='remote:port')`.  This allows you to `args.port`, while showing the same help.